# AJAX POST-method not allowed Error 405

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send an email when I click on a button. For this I make an ajax call to a php file:

Ajax call:

```
 function postAjax(arr) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "../BackEnd/AjaxHandler.php",
         data: { 'action': 'mail' },
         type: "GET"
     });
 }
```

php file (Ajaxhandler.php)

```
<?php   
   if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
   $action = $_GET['action'];
   switch($action){
      case 'mail':
         mail('N.Suhner@wigasoft.ch', 'Mein Betreff', 'tsest'); 
         break;
      }
   }
?>
```

call:

```
$("#mailto").click(function() {
   postAjax(listOfTasks);
 });
```

In the call I make some more things but these are not relevant (styling).

When I click on the button I got an error that the POST-method is not allowed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try adding dataType "JSONP" in your ajax properties

Comment: please copy paste the error here from your browser console

Comment: Please post your route file.

Comment: perhaps you got a 405 post method not allowed? try with type: "get" and dataType: "jsonp".

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, You have entered the wrong keyword... Please check following code

Your code should be like following....

```
function postAjax(arr) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../_BackEnd/AjaxHandler.php",
      crossDomain: true,
      data: { id: 12 }
   });
}
```

**php file:**

```
<?php        
     $message = "This is a text!";
     mail('example@mail.ch', 'subject', $message);       
?>
```

**EDIT**

**Html**

```
<form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Comment: I changed it already see the answer from @Exprator but I got still the same error.

Comment: @NiZelooer Let me give you test code about the same, Please check edit section

Comment: I changed the jquery like yours and In the console I got the error that the Method is Not Allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
 function postAjax(arr) {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../_BackEnd/AjaxHandler.php",
   data: { id: 12 },
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
   }
  });
 }
```

Comment: sadly didn't helped.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, if you got 405 post method not allowed, a workaround (well, not really a solution) can be trying with these settings:

```
function postAjax(arr) {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "../_BackEnd/AjaxHandler.php?id=12",
   dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(d){
      console.log(d);
  }).fail(function(j){
      console.log(j.responseText);
  });
 }
```

Comment: I changed it like your Answer and now I got an 404.3 - Not found error.

Comment: It sais that the page can't visited because a configuration extension. When it's a script I need to add a handler. When it should be downloaded I sneed to add a MIME-assignment

Comment: You should try to understand what code does in AjaxHandler.php. You should post a more bits of code to understand what's inside AjaxHandler.php. Can you access this code?

Comment: In Ajaxhandler.php is nothing more ^^.

Comment: What if you debug the script commenting mail() function and try to echo something back to js? Perhaps can be something chained within mail() ini configuration params or headers? What if you do not pass _post nor _get data? There must be something "disturbing" the script. Perhaps an unknown for us server configuration? I'll try simplest ajax call and then adding more features.

Comment: see also my updated answer: removed data, attached params to url, changed datatype jsonp to json. Try to see if it works. Play with datatype to return back html instead of json if necessary.

Comment: I removed the mail in the php file and made a echo (error) then I copied the code in you answer and tested it too but also here I got an error(404.3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=404.3 I think you should then look for this type of error you got. Hope this helps.